# TFS 2012: Change work item type

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have TFS 2012 installed. I want to change work item types, e.g. from bug to test case or something else. How can I do it? Maybe configure process template or tfs somehow? I have admin permissions, but don't know what and where to change.
I've already tried to export these items to Excel, but "Work item type" field in exported file is read-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change a work item type; however, you can create a copy of a work item to another type through the web access or Visual Studio. See [this blog post](http://blog.damianbrady.com.au/2013/10/10/how-to-change-a-work-items-type-in-team-foundation-server/) for detailed instructions.

Comment: And don't forget to add a link to the original work item for traceability.

Comment: @GiulioVian, that think will be created automatically by the copy process